# Calling FormTagHelper's from asset's folder

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a rails 4.2 application where I would like to use some `html` templates files stored out of the `app\views` folder. I placed these templates in the `app\assets\templates` folder and added the `.erb` to some of them as they will need some server side work.

I have the following error being produced when attempting to use a `email_field_tag` from a `.html.erb` file in the `app\assets\templates` folder:

> ```
> undefined method `email_field_tag' for  #<#<Class:0x00000006e51d10>:0x00000006a79260>
> ```

the code around the error is as simple as:

```
<%= email_field_tag :email %>
```

The funny part is that the same code works if placed in the  `app\views\mycontroler\myview.html.erb` file where it originated from.

I would appreciate ideas on how to address this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh well... It turns out it was a simple solution, using the following addressed the issue:

```
<%= ActionController::Base.helpers.email_field_tag :email %>
```